# Can migrations.RunPython run arbitrary python code?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I want to include the processing of many many raw SQL files (functions, triggers ...) at the end of my migrations.

I thought to write my [own Special operation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#writing-your-own/), but I've been told to use the [django.db.migrations.RunPython()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#runpython) command instead and put some django.db.migrations.RunSQL() commands in the called function.

As RunPython() takes a callable with 2 instances (an App and a SchemaEditor) I seriously doubt (I reviewed the source a bit)  that I can call a function with pure python code, it seems like it could only perform ORM manipulations. Should I use execute_from_command_line() inside the RunPython ? Or is that way doomed to failure ? Or doing things poorly ?

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import migrations

def load_sql(apps, schema_editor):

    from os.path import normpath, dirname, isfile, join
    from os import listdir

    sql_folder_path = '/backoffice/sql/'

    def load_raw_sql(folder_inside):
        folder_path = join(sql_folder_path, folder_inside)
        sql_files = [join(folder_path, f) for f in listdir(folder_path) if isfile(join(folder_path, f))]
        for sql_file in sql_files:
            with open(sql_file, 'r') as g:
                migrations.RunSQL(g.read())

    folders = ['functions', 'index', 'triggers']

    for folder in folders:
        load_raw_sql(folder)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('app1', '0001_squashed_0018_auto_20150616_0708'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(load_sql),
    ]
```

We are using PostGreSQL.
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: "I seriously doubt...that I can call a function with pure python code, it seems like it could only perform ORM manipulations." This sentence is really throwing me. What do you mean by pure Python vs only ORM manipulations? All Django is written in Python. What is "impure" about it?

Comment: Wrong words, but I mean that I've only seen models-like implementationsinside runPython() commands, and I want to know if I could write any python code in it ?

Comment: Presumably. Have you tried it? What would stop you? Even those models are just Python code.

Comment: I've tried the above code, seems like I am doing things the wrong way, I don't get any output if I put print statements, my django_migrations table gets an entry for the migration when I run the code, so it doesn't fail.  
I can't figure out if i need the [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlparse) `sqlparse` package and if i should use RunSQL or manually use a database connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd have thought it fairly obvious that an operation called `RunPython` can, er, run python code, but the short answer is yes, you can do whatever you want in a `RunPython` operation.

The main thing to consider is that the code you write needs to keep working in the future (or until you squash your migrations) because every time you run `migrate` or `makemigrations`, all the previous migrations are used to derive the current state of the database.

Comment: Thanks, so I should assume that it's my code that's broken right ?

Answer (score 1):

django.db.migration.RunPython can accept any python code.
The problem here was that I tried to use RunSQL() inside the call I made with RunPython(), which seems not to work in my case because I didn't provide an app and a schema editor.
I managed to run my batch of SQL files thanks to a cursor and wrote inside my callable:

```
from django.db import migrations
cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
sql = "FOO;"
cursor.execute(sql)
```